# how to use command argument?

Tags: c

there is an error in fopen.c how can i solve it?
error in assigning argv[1], argv[2] to ft, fs.

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  //FILE *fs, *ft ;
  char ch ;
  //ft = fopen ("d:\\out.txt", "w") ;        

  fs = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
  if ( fs == NULL )        {               
    puts ( "Cannot open source file" ) ;                           
    exit(1) ;  
  }
  //fs = fopen("d:\in_file.txt","r") ;

  ft = fopen( argv[2], "w" );
  if ( ft == NULL ){               
    puts ( "Cannot open target file") ;               
    exit(1) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be checking `argc`; it's the count of arguments passed on the command line. Your code as is accesses `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` when they may not exist.Also, what does "error in assigning" mean? What error? There aren't any mindreaders here, as far as I know, and we can't see your monitor either.

Comment: Right now *ft* and *fs* does not exists since their declarations are commented out on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. It's a program that copies vowels and linefeeds ('\n') from the file specified in the 1st argument to the file in the 2nd argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *fi, *fo;
  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "syntax: %s in out\n", argv[0][0]?argv[0]:"program");
    fprintf(stderr, "copies vowels and linefeeds from in to out\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fi = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fi) {
    perror("input file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {
    fo = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!fo) {
      perror("output file");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
      int ch;
      while ((ch = fgetc(fi)) != EOF) {
        switch (ch) {
          case 'a': case 'e': case 'i':
          case 'o': case 'u': case '\n':
              fputc(ch, fo);
              break;
          default:
              break; /* do nothing */
        }
      }
      fclose(fo);
    }
    fclose(fi);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it with the source above as input (`./a.out 5292243.c 5292243.vowels`), the resulting file contains

```
iueio
iuei

iaiiaaa
io
ia
ieaiouaaoa
ieoieoeaieeeoioou
ei

ioea
ii
eoiuie
ei
ee
ooea
io
eoouuie
ei
ee
i
ieei
i
aeaaeeaei
aeoaeuaeuo
eaueaooi


oeo

oei

eu
```

Comment: Of course this functionality is much better when applied to a standard filter (using `stdin` for input and `stdout` for output) instead of command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

At first, there a huge indentation problem in your code. Please solve it. [EDIT: Now it is ok]

Second, what kind of error? Both fs and ft are equal to NULL?
Instead of using puts to display error message, you can use perror(const char *s). This will add informations to your message knowing the stat of the errno variable.

Comment: what you posted is not an answer to the question. If you can't answer the question because it's vague/not well defined, state so in the comments (or flag the question if it's inappropriate).

Comment: first my command line have 3 arg :>compilefex in_file.txt out.txt ,,,the program works well without the command argument it takes the infile from D and make it postfix into out file as you see the comments show but after using command arguments it seems that fs and ft does not take the value of argv[1] and argv[2]

Comment: You should complete your original post instead of posting comments.